generating proto file for reactjs with protoc command show error: 'protoc-gen-js' is not recognized
i want generate a proto file for reactjs
this is the commands I tested:
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:. *.proto

protoc -I=. ./data.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.

and I get below error:
'protoc-gen-js' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--js_out: protoc-gen-js: Plugin failed with status code 1.

and I downloaded these packages in c:/ drive and added them to system variable:
protobuf-javascript-3.21.2-win64
protoc-27.1-win64
protoc-gen-grpc-web-1.5.0-windows-x86_64.exe

what is the problem? and how to fix it?
also check these links too
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript/issues/127
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript/pull/208

PS D:\test codes\foperix1> protoc --proto_path=. data.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.
'protoc-gen-grpc-web' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--grpc-web_out: protoc-gen-grpc-web: Plugin failed with status code 1.

It's confusing and the repo's protobuf-javascript README is unclear.
When you run protoc --js_out=, the --js_out refers to a separate binary (plugin, in this case called protoc-gen-js) that must either be in the path or specified using the --plugin= flag.
The plugin name (e.g. protoc-gen-js) follows a pattern in which the protoc-gen prefix is removed and _out and _opt may be added to the revised name to form the protoc flags (i.e. --js_out).
Corrollary: when you add --js_out to protoc, protoc looks (absent a --plugin= flag) in the path for a binary called protoc-gen-js to invoke.
You can download the latest release here and I recommend putting the plugin in your path.
Then try the protoc command again.

i followed below instruction and removed all versions fromfolders and name of packages and 2 js files generated
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/767#issuecomment-609438604
